# Bootbox confirm not working - example works

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootbox

I have a table with the following delete button with a form (Laravel).

```
<!-- Delete Button -->
<form action="{{url('admin/users')}}/@{{ user.id }}" method="POST" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" id="delete">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-btn fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

This is my script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootbox/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#delete').submit(function(e) {
    var currentForm = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            currentForm.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
</script>
```

When I try the bootbox example it works.

bootbox.alert("Hello world!");

I can't find my mistake. Can you guys help me?

**// EDIT 1:**

Bootstrap CSS is in the  and this is my order at the bottom:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootbox/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

And after that follows my  code.

If I just try the example from bootbox

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
    Example.show("Hello world callback");
});
```

It works without any problem.

**// EDIT 2 - Solution**

I found the error... I am also using vue js and the delete button was inside a vue js div and does not work. Outside of Vue JS there is no problem.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The Modal is not showing

Comment: Any idea? Tried everything but did not work

Comment: Do you see any errors in the developer console? Have you included jQuery and Bootstrap (both CSS and JS) prior to bootbox.js?

Comment: See my edit above.